# Streamreader Throwing ObjectDisposed Exception When Reading FTP DirectoryList With Spaces

Tags: c#, ftp, async-await, streamreader

I am working on a simple FTP application that reads the server inventory of a server and pulls down new files.  In order to do this, I must read the directory list for its contents.  The FTP ListDirectoryDetails works perfectly when the filenames and/or subdirectory names does not contain white space.  However, if the directory has white space (i.e. spaces in the name), my readers throws an ObjectDisposed exception.  The stack trace contains no user code besides the method below (everything other method call is in the framework).

I have googled and googled and googled some more without luck explaining this exception.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

```
public async Task<List<string>> ListDirectoryDetailsAsync()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        var request = CreateRequest(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails);

        using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                list.Add(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Try : reader.ReadLine().Trim()

Comment: Thanks but the problem I'm facing is with white space in the directory/file name itself--not white space in the beginnning or end.  So, example, <ftp://server/directory with spaces/file with spaces.csv>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code locally against the FileZilla Server (version 0.9.57 beta). Your code read directory names with white spaces very well. I assume your problem is specific to your data or environment. Capturing the network traffic might give some insight.

Comment: I thought it would too!  I must admit to be shocked to have this problem.

I have not tried against the FileZilla server but it is certainly worth a shot.  Also, as the bulk of my experience in tracking down network issues is from a browser to the server, capturing this type of network traffic is uncharted territory for me.  Do you have any good suggestions as to a tool I should run while making the call?  It is probably worth mentioning at this point that I do not have direct access to the FTP server (hosted solution).

Comment: I would suggest to install FileZilla server on your development environment first and create some file / directory names that cause this exception with your production environment. If the exception still occurs then I would rather search on the client side (e.g. .net framework version; my experiment was done with 4.6.1). For capturing network traffic I recommend Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: I have installed FileZilla Server on my dev machine and can sucessfully recreate the scenario.  Apparently, when using ReadLine() on a file name that contains spaces, the underlying  stream of the StreamReader is disposed.  The IDisposedObjectException occurs when the loop attempts to see if another ReadLine() is necessary.

Comment: I wonder why your code is working in my envrionment but not in yours... Perhaps different .net Framework versions ? I suggest to create a small console application using the newest framework and execute your code fragment in isolation.

Comment: Just finished a simple console app on .Net 4.6.1.  It is definitely environmental.  When running against my local FTP instance, it works without a hitch.  When attempting to connect to my prod server, it bombs out on the same directory.  

I tried wireshark but since connecting to the FTP server requires explicit TLS, the packets were all encrypted and not much help. Fun fact--apparently the SSLKEYLOG setting of Firefox no longer creates a (pre)masterKeyLog file.

I'm going to reach out to my host and see if their server has any log files I can review.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you for your update. Good luck in hunting this down.

Comment: Finally found the issue!  At the end of the day, it was due to a mal-encoded URI.  When creating my FtpWebRequest, I was passing a URI object into the constructor.  That URI was given a string to form the uri.  I did not put a '/' on the end of the URI when changing working directories.  Apparently, new URI(@"ftp://server/directory with spaces") does not encode.

Thanks for all your help troubleshooting this issue.